# Using the Maputnik style editor to create MapBox/MapLibre style for GeoServer mapbox vector tiles served in custom projection

Tags: geoserver, mapbox-vector-tile, maputnik

I tried following https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/draft/edu/en/vector_tiles/vector_tiles-styling_maputnik.html even if my goal is not to create a server side style to limit visibility but rather a MapBox/MapLibre spec style for the client because the guide gives advice on how to connect the Maputnik editor to a GeoServer mvt layer.

The connection string is unfortunately missing from the guide but as far as I can tell it should be similar to the `tiles` URL of the style file, i.e https://..geoserverdomain/geoserver/themes/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetTile&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=themes:layergrouplayer&STYLE=&TILEMATRIX=3006_vt:{z}&TILEMATRIXSET=3006_vt&FORMAT=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile&TILECOL={x}&TILEROW={y}

Setting up a Vector (XYZ) URL (as in the guide) with the above link and then adding a layer with a `source-layer: layergrouplayer` the editor requests tiles form the given location but the tileColumn request values are out of index.

So my questions are as follows: Is creating a style file for a MapBox vector tile layer in a custom projection (not 900913) supported by the Maputnik editor? If so can someone see if I've done something obviously wrong?

The goal is to not need to write rather long background layer style files by hand, if realistic.